# Java List of Objects sort by specific object which is not sorting

Tags: java, json, java-8

Am having the following JSONArray which am trying to sort it. So, for that am converting my JSONArray into ArrayList then am sorting them and converting back into JSONArray.

Please find the initial JSONArray (which is not in sorting order).

```
[  
   {  

      "code":"TE-7000-8003-W",
      "id":"13342",

   },
   {  
      "code":"TE-7000-8003",
      "id":"13163",
   },
   {  
      "code":"TE-7000-8003-WK",
     "id":"11573",
   },
   {  
      "code":"TE-7000-8003S",
      "id":"11565",

   },
   {  
      "code":"TE-7000-8003-K",
      "id":"11557",
   }
]
```

Please find my below code which am converting my JSONArray into ArrayList and sorting them.

```
Item item=null;
List<Item> newItemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
for (int i=0;i<resultJSONArray.length();i++) {
    JSONObject jobj = resultJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
    item = new Item();
    item.setId(jobj.optString("id"));
    item.setCode(jobj.optString("code"));
    newItemList.add(item);
}

 newItemList
  .stream()
  .sorted((object1, object2) -> object1.getCode().compareTo(object2.getCode()));

Iterator<Item> itr = newItemList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Item item1=itr.next();
    System.out.println("Item----->"+item1.getCode());
}
```

Following is the output am getting which is not sorted order

```
Item----->TE-7000-8003-W
Item----->TE-7000-8003
Item----->TE-7000-8003-WK
Item----->TE-7000-8003S
Item----->TE-7000-8003-K
```

Am expecting the result like below :

```
Item----->TE-7000-8003
Item----->TE-7000-8003S
Item----->TE-7000-8003-K
Item----->TE-7000-8003-W
Item----->TE-7000-8003-WK
```

Comment: You're not assigning the result of the sorting operation to anything. So you're printing the original, not sorted list. Just use list.sort() if you want to sort in-place.

Comment: Use newItemList.sort(yourComparator) to sort a list instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a stream and use sorted you don't change the actual list. So you could do the following:

```
List<Item> sortedItemList =newItemList
.stream()
.sorted((object1, object2) -> object1.getCode().compareTo(object2.getCode()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or better sort the list with the sort method

```
newItemList
.sort((object1, object2) -> object1.getCode().compareTo(object2.getCode()));
```

And you could use `Comparator.comparing(Item::getCode)` to replace the comparator

```
newItemList
.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getCode));
```

Comment: And the comparator could be simplified to `Comparator.comparing(Item::getCode)`

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple `Comparator` to apply on your list just like that ;

```
newItemList
.sort((firstObj, secondObj) -> firstObj.getCode().compareTo(secondObj.getCode()));
```

Or more simple ;

```
newItemList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getCode)); //dont forget to write getter method of Code variable.
```

Comment: Item::getCode can't possibly be a Comparator. You probably mean `Comparator.comparing(Item::getCode)`

Comment: Thanks for your attention @JBNizet :)